# Mobile Safari (iOS8) crashing during HTML5 Canvas based game

Tags: html, canvas, ios8, mobile-safari, impactjs

We have an ImpactJS based (canvas) HTML5 game, which since the iOS8 update seems to be crashing fairly frequently. We've tried it in a UIWebView based wrapper, and it seems to be ok. In a WKWebView wrapper, we get crashes, same as in Safari.

The crash logs don't show much (or at least I don't know how to get anything useful from them), but the exception type is `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) with a subtype of KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000`.

I'm really at a loss as to why it crashes. The game runs fine on older versions of Mobile Safari, and is fine on Android.

How would I solve this, or failing that, are there any techniques I can use to narrow down where the issue is coming from?